# Play continues alarms when my Python script Stop with Error

Tags: python, python-3.x, spyder

I am not an expert in Python, however i have made some script which runs automatically after every 1 minute, however sometime it stop automatically while throwing some error and this loop ( i.e playing every 1 minute stops) So is there any alarms mechanism which plays continues sound when there is an error or when this loop stop. so that i don't have to watch my script every 1 minute to check if the script is running or has been stop.

> ```
> print(current_time+' '+'in'+' '+ExcelWrkbook.Name)
> time.sleep(60)
> ```

or after 1 minutes it run even there is an error. Below Error comes when my script stops

> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "D:\Santanu Maji\NSE_DATA_COLLECTION(NEW)\NSE_DATA_COLLECTION\ExcelSheetRecordNew_03.py", line 126, in 
> ExcelWrksht.Range("E3").Value=CED4
> File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\win32com\client\dynamic.py", line 565, in **setattr**
> self.*oleobj*.Invoke(entry.dispid, 0, invoke_type, 0, value)
> com_error: (-2147352567, 'Exception occurred.', (0, None, None, None, 0, -2146777998), None)

Comment: Is `ExcelWrkbook` a typo?

Comment: No. It is right, because my script runs most of the time. To grab my attention instantly i want some alarm mechanism.